# Can not delete the file zip uploaded using CodeIgniter Zip library

Tags: codeigniter, upload, zip

I am using Codeigniter to upload a zip file and extract it to a folder using upload and zip library of Codeigniter 1.7.2

Everything Ok, but my code fails to delete the zip file after extract the zip file using extract method.

I got the message 'access deny'.

Anyone help me?

Comment: How are you trying to delete the file? FTP? Through your application? Where does the error come from, the server or Codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

try restarting your PHP and APACHE, perhaps they have locked the handle to the file !